# Is there a way to reference back to last expression in chain for use as parameter in function (C#)

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Hi I have the following code:

```
log.Entry = (newEntry ?? "").Substring(0,Math.Min((newEntry ?? "").Length, 50));
```

log.Entry is a database field of nvarchar(50)
So I want to do is limit to max 50 chars but also have a null check so I don't try to run string-functions on null which might throw exceptions.(?)

My question is can the second (newEntry ?? "") be simplified by some sort of operator? 
This is already evaluated once and might not need to be evaluated again. 
I looking for a one-liner so it would be something like a lambda-style syntax. (but I guess not actual lambda).

Comment: why not store `newEntry ?? ""` into a new variable? Anyway even *if* you´d call this twice it should not have a huge impact on your performance as long as `newEntry` isn´t a query-expression on itws own.

Comment: Or, `log.Entry= (newEntry!=null ? newEntry.Substring(0, Math.Min(newEntry.Length, 50)):"");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always do the following:

```
var logEntry = new string(newEntry?.Take(50).ToArray());
```

To bear in mind:

- `new string(null)` will creat an empty string `""`.
- `Enumerable.Take(n)` will take the first `n` elements of the sequence. If there are less that `n` elements, then it will take the whole sequence.
- Performance is significantly worse than other solutions, where it is not necessary to enumerate the `string`.

Comment: This won't compile. you need `... Take(50).ToArray()`. But nice idea!

Comment: @RoleyBaxter this code hides intent of what you are doing (I bet average developer will read this code several times to understand that you are picking substring here) and it gives you the worst performance impact (creating iterator, iterating characters *one-by-one* until counter reaches zero, then picking all this characters and allocating array, then passing array to string constructor and allocating new string)

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy Yes, its an option, I never said it was the best. Performance is worse than other solutions, I'll update the answer to make sure that is clear. I do disagree slightly with intent, `Take` and `new string(char[] chars)` should be pretty easy to understand.

Answer (score 5):

```
log.Entry = newEntry?.Substring(0, Math.Min(newEntry.Length, 50)) ?? "";
```

Or drop `?? ""` at the end if you want `log.Entry` to be null if `newEntry` is null:

```
log.Entry = newEntry?.Substring(0, Math.Min(newEntry.Length, 50));
```

Comment: nice option , Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use

```
newEntry?.Substring(0, Math.Min(newEntry.Length, 50))
```

This way, as soon as `newEntry` is `null`, the call to `SubString(...)` is never invoked and the entire expression is evaluated to `null`. Once `SubString()` *is* reached, you no longer have to check for nullity and you can settle with `Math.Min(newEntry.Length, 50)`.

Comment: Good explanation and good answer with null-conditional operator usage

Answer (score 0):

I guess:

```
newEntry = newEntry ?? "";
og.Entry = newEntry.Substring(0,Math.Min(newEntry.Length, 50));
```

Answer (score 0):

Almost all the rest of answers are taking advantage of the Safe Navigation Operator `?.`,that was introduced in C# 6 if i'm not wrong. But the tag in your question is C# 4.0, so I think this would work for you:

```
log.Entry= (newEntry!=null ? newEntry.Substring(0, Math.Min(newEntry.Length, 50)):"");
```

This uses the [`? Operator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Though other answers produce valid results, they tend to produce repetitive code which hides your intent (also there might be performance issues if you'll each time create LINQ iterators and instantiate new strings from characters).

For strings trimming I usually use extension methods:

```
public static string TrimTo(this string value, int maxLength)
{
    if (value == null || value.Length <= maxLength)
       return value;

    return value.Substring(0, maxLength);
}
```

They give you clean and readable code wich is easy to reuse in several places:

```
log.Entry = newEntry.TrimTo(50);
```

Consider also to add ellipsis to the end of trimmed string.